# Find $(\ell,m,n)$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\ell k$, $\sum\limits_{k=\ell+1}^mk$ and $\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^nk$ are in geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find one triple of integers $(l, m, n)$, where $2 < l < m < n$ such that

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{l} k, \displaystyle \sum_{k=l+1}^{m} k,\displaystyle \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} k\;$ is a geometric sequence.

My attempted work :

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{l} k = \frac{l(l+1)}{2}$

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=l+1}^{m} k = \frac{(m-l)(m+l+1)}{2}$

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=m+1}^{n} k = \frac{(n-m)(n+m+1)}{2}$

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Try to write down the relation that make them a geometric sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the three sums, in order, $A_0, A_1, A_2$; these are in geometric progression iff $A_1 = \lambda A_0$ and $A_2 = \lambda^2 A_0$ for some $\lambda$, or equivalently, iff the quantity $$\Delta := A_0 A_2 - A_1^2$$ vanishes.

A posteriori, it's not easy to see how to solve this by hand: Writing the quantity on the left-hand side as a polynomial in terms of $l, m, n$ does not give something visibly tractable. If one searches with a CAS for solutions with $l, m \leq 10^3$, one can spot a pattern among some of the solutions: For all $l$,
$$m = (2 l + 2) l, \qquad n = (4 l^2 + 6 l + 3 l) l$$
is a solution with $\lambda = (2 l + 1)^2$.

There are other, 'sporadic' solutions $(l, m, n)$ that do not fall into this pattern. The only ones with $n < 10^3$ are:
$$(8, 11, 13), \quad (5, 9, 14), \quad (3, 11, 36), \quad (7, 27, 97) .$$
The first of these is the only one mentioned in this answer with $\lambda < 1$. (These do not exhaust the sporadic solutions, by the way: $(48, 2183, 98283)$ is another.)

All of the solutions mentioned here correspond to factorizations of $\Delta$ of the particular form
$\Delta = l (l + 1) [n + (\mu + 1)](n - \mu)$, which might be a clue to how one could solve this manually.

Comment: I think it's hard to find the answer by hand. Thank you very much for your help, Travis.

Comment: I think so, too, unless there's a clever observation I'm missing. And you're welcome.

Comment: @carat: A little staring reveals a pattern that's obscured if you just look at the solutions with $l < 8$ say. Most, but not all, of the solutions fall into a particular family given by polynomial expressions for $m$ and $n$ in $l$. I've rewritten my answer accordingly.

Comment: Strange. your solution  was written 4h ago, but did appear only when I published mine... Anyway, I have found a similar thing, but did not explored rational $\lambda$ for sporadic solutions. I wonder though if the subset found for $\lambda$ integer is the only one ?

Comment: No, the solution $(3, 156, 7068)$ has $\lambda = 2040$.

Comment: $\frac{l(l+1)}{2} \cdot \frac{(n-m)(n+m+1)}{2} = \frac{(m-l)^2(m+l+1)^2}{4}$. I wonder how one can factor the LHS If we try $l=3$, we have $6 \cdot \frac{(n-m)(n+m+1)}{2} = \frac{(m-3)^2(m+4)^2}{4}$. Can someone show me how to get one solution manually ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is easier not to work with the truncated series but with triangular numbers directly

$T_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k=\frac{n(n+1)}2$

If we call $x,y,z$ your three sums, and $a$ the reason of the geometric serie, we get :

$\begin{cases}
x = T_l\\
x+y = (1+a)\,x = T_m\\
x+y+z = (1+a+a^2)\,x = T_n 
\end{cases}$

So we have to found $a,l,m,n$ such that $\frac{T_m}{T_l}=(1+a)$ and $\frac{T_n}{T_l}=(1+a+a^2)$.

But even with these simpler formulations I do not see how to carry on without brute force enumeration. Here are for instance, some results with $0<a<2000$ and $0<l<500$.

*Note that I took $a$ integer, but nothing a priori prevent $a$ to be rational $a$. Though, I have tested for $\frac 12$ and $\frac 13$ and found none in the extended range $0<l<50000$.*

```
a=2     T5=15    T9=45        T14=105           sqrt(a)=1.41421 m/l=1.8 n/l=2.8 
a=9     T1=1     T4=10        T13=91            sqrt(a)=3   m/l=4   n/l=13    
a=10    T3=6     T11=66       T36=666           sqrt(a)=3.16228 m/l=3.66667 n/l=12
a=25    T2=3     T12=78       T62=1953          sqrt(a)=5   m/l=6   n/l=31    
a=49    T3=6     T24=300      T171=14706        sqrt(a)=7   m/l=8   n/l=57    
a=81    T4=10    T40=820      T364=66430        sqrt(a)=9   m/l=10  n/l=91    
a=121   T5=15    T60=1830     T665=221445       sqrt(a)=11  m/l=12  n/l=133   
a=169   T6=21    T84=3570     T1098=603351      sqrt(a)=13  m/l=14  n/l=183   
a=225   T7=28    T112=6328    T1687=1423828     sqrt(a)=15  m/l=16  n/l=241   
a=289   T8=36    T144=10440   T2456=3017196     sqrt(a)=17  m/l=18  n/l=307   
a=361   T9=45    T180=16290   T3429=5880735     sqrt(a)=19  m/l=20  n/l=381   
a=441   T10=55   T220=24310   T4630=10720765    sqrt(a)=21  m/l=22  n/l=463   
a=529   T11=66   T264=34980   T6083=18504486    sqrt(a)=23  m/l=24  n/l=553   
a=625   T12=78   T312=48828   T7812=30517578    sqrt(a)=25  m/l=26  n/l=651   
a=729   T13=91   T364=66430   T9841=48427561    sqrt(a)=27  m/l=28  n/l=757   
a=841   T14=105  T420=88410   T12194=74352915   sqrt(a)=29  m/l=30  n/l=871   
a=961   T15=120  T480=115440  T14895=110937960  sqrt(a)=31  m/l=32  n/l=993   
a=1089  T16=136  T544=148240  T17968=161433496  sqrt(a)=33  m/l=34  n/l=1123  
a=1225  T17=153  T612=187578  T21437=229783203  sqrt(a)=35  m/l=36  n/l=1261  
a=1369  T18=171  T684=234270  T25326=320715801  sqrt(a)=37  m/l=38  n/l=1407  
a=1521  T19=190  T760=289180  T29659=439842970  sqrt(a)=39  m/l=40  n/l=1561  
a=1681  T20=210  T840=353220  T34460=593763030  sqrt(a)=41  m/l=42  n/l=1723  
a=1849  T21=231  T924=427350  T39753=790170381  sqrt(a)=43  m/l=44  n/l=1893
```

Anyway this is encouraging because except for $a=2$ and $a=10$ there seem to be a pattern for this subset.

If we take $k\in\mathbb N^*$ then $a=(2k+1)^2$

And we have $l=k$ and $\frac ml=2k+2$ and $\frac nl=(\frac ml)^2-(\frac ml)+1$

I have plugged the values and verified the calculation with symbolic software, the subset below is always a solution of the problem for $l\in\mathbb N^*$

$\begin{cases}
a=(2l+1)^2 \\
m = 2l(l+1)\\
n = 4l^3+6l^2+3l
\end{cases}\implies\begin{cases}T_m=(1+a)\,T_l\\T_n=(1+a+a^2)\,T_l\end{cases}$

Can we go further ?

Are this subset and the two solutions $(T_5,\,T_9,\,T_{14}\,,a=2)$ and $(T_3,\,T_{11},\,T_{36},\,a=10)$ the only solutions of the problem at least for $a$ integer ?

---

After editing my program, here are some additionnal solutions found by enumeration in the range : $l<100,m<10^9$

$\begin{array}{ll}
a=10 & (3,11,36)\\
a=2040 & (3,156,7068)\\
a=2 & (5,9,14)\\
a=\frac{25}{2} & (7,27,97)\\
a=\frac 56 & (8,11,13)\\
a=\frac{28379}{14} & (48,2183,98283)\\
a=\frac{5504015}{14} & (48,30408,19066491)\\
\end{array}$

Comment: Thank you for the good point on Geometric ratio but calculating equiptments are not allowed in the test.

Comment: That's maybe why you accepted the other answer found with a CAS... bah.

Comment: I accepted Travis's answer mainly because of his opinion on solving this problem manually, not the solutions by CAS. However, finding the pattern of the solutions found by computer programme is additional interesting information.:)

Comment: ok, lol, I understand :-). At first the problem remembered me of the hotel problem "it has n floors, poor people occupy the first m floors and rich people the top floors, price of rooms is increasing with altitude, it is k*i dollars at floor i, find n,m such that poors and riches pay the same total amount". In this problem, triangular numbers appear too, but it can be reduced to solving a Pell-Fermat equation (in this case reduct fractions of $\sqrt{2}$ are involved) and can be solved manually and is close to the case $a=1$. But yours seems harder, and the same technique doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for the nice problem. $2(1+2+...+m) = 1+2+...+n$. I can get $(2n+1)^2 - 2(2m+1)^2 = -1$ which is negative Pell's equation. With some manipulation I obtain $x_n = \frac{1}{2}[(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1} + (1-\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}]$ and $y_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}[(1+\sqrt{2})^{2n+1} - (1-\sqrt{2})^{2n+1}]$. $n = \frac{x_n-1}{2}$ and $m = \frac{y_n-1}{2}$. We have $(m,n) = (2,3), (14,20), (84,119), ...$